# What is 'filename' in the code of Transfer Learning using MNIST dataset?

Tags: python, csv, keras, classification, mnist

The code for classification of MNIST dataset using Transfer Learning is given in the link https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/transfer-learning-the-art-of-fine-tuning-a-pre-trained-model/

I am not able to understand what 'filename' stands in the code? Also, why the dataset is loaded twice in the code.

I have seen code using load_img() function but still, I am not able to run the given code without error as 'filename' is unknown as it is not defined in the link.

The MNIST dataset consists of two files 'mnist_train.csv' and 'mnist_test.csv'. There is code where the .csv files are being converted into images but then they have a single .csv file for every image. Here, there are only two .csv files for all the images present in train and test.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset is in a csv format, and has column `filename` which contains the image name in it. 
I imagine the file has the following structure:

```
   filename    label
0  file1.jpg    1
1  file2.jpg    8
2  file3.jpg    5
....
```

They read the csv file into `train`

```
train=pd.read_csv("R/Data/Train/train.csv")
```

and then use the loop to open each file given in the dataframe

```
for i in range(len(train)):
temp_img=image.load_img(train_path+train['filename'][i],target_size=(224,224))
```

Using the above code the image is loaded and resized

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
labels = []
pixels =[]
for index, row in train_data.iterrows():
    label=np.zeros(10)
    label[row["label"]]=1
    labels.append(label)
    pixels.append(row[1:])
labels = np.array(labels)
pixels = np.array(pixels)
```

I have added the code for loading the data from csv file you posted in the comments

Comment: MNIST dataset in .csv format is given in this link https://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/

Comment: It would be great if you can check it as there is no column named filename and the  file is starting from labels in first column. After running the code, error generated is "KeyError: 'filename'". May be I have to make that column in it. Is it?

Comment: The MNIST csv file you are using is different one from the site you posted in your question. The MNIST csv is in the format `label,pixel-1 to pixel-784`. So you have to load your data differently. I have added how to load data from such a csv file in my answer